# auto-pst-pdf not working

Tags: matlab, auto-pst-pdf

I have used laprint within matlab to generate a simple graph:

```
set(0, 'defaulttextinterpreter','none')
figure(1), clf
plot([1 2])
ylabel('A straight line')
laprint
```

which gives me line.eps and line .tex. I then try to include this with latex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[on]{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \matlabfig{line}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I run:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape foo.tex
```

but the result (foo-pics.pdf) is this:

[image]

So it looks like the symbol substitution hasn't worked. What has gone wrong?

I running CentOs 6.5 and pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13

Comment: Doesn't auto-pst-pdf require using `pstricks`? Can your matlab graph be exported to pstricks? Or consider using the `epstopdf` package.

Comment: If I do that will I still get the latex typesetting for the axis labels ? Adding \usepackage{pstricks} didn't change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: what happens with `\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}`?

Comment: tried \usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf} but it's exactly the same

Comment: @Lefti: I you want to replace text with LaTeX text, you should use  `psfrag` or `psfragx`. Along with psfragx, is a Mathlab script called `LaPrint` that creates a .tex file for the labels and text within a mathlab graph. That done, you can use `epstopdf`.

Comment: could you please provide an example because I am unsure of what you mean. I'm already using LaPrint to generate a .tex file with the tags. The issue is that these are not being applied to the graph. I thought that the auto-pst-pdf package already handled the .eps to .pdf conversion.